# Images issue outlook and OWA

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

Outlook email images is not visible in the body on the email, same is the case with Outlook on the web

tried on different browsers
Version is Outlook 2016
Issue is on MAC OS
Sender is sending correctly but images are not seen at the recipient end
seNDER is only using Outlook for web

Comment: You really need to show the relevant snippets of your code as well as the resulting HTML constraint the img tabs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.